# How do I add a blur BEHIND an html element?

Tags: javascript, css, blur, gaussianblur

I've dug through the internet and found some things that seem to be going in the right direction but nothing that seemed like a complete solution. Here's what I found:

- The upcoming CSS property `backdrop-filter`, which is currently only supported in Safari and behind a Chrome developer flag. Exactly what I need, but it needs better support.
- The JavaScript library Blur.js, which seems to have all but disappeared from the internet. (Even the official website leads to a GoDaddy page.) It may have been a solution but I'm not sure what happened to the project.
- The JavaScript library StackBlur, which seems to be a brilliant blurring solution, but I haven't the slightest idea how I would use it to blur BEHIND an element.

Any ideas? Perhaps someone has used StackBlur to do this and has a CodePen I could poke through or something? Basically, I have a grid of element each using jQuery UI Draggable that I would like to make translucent with a nice blur behind each one. The blur needs to update as expected when the elements are dragged around.

One last thought. Right now what I'm using is a pure CSS "solution", but it has some annoying limitations. If you are going to suggest a solution with only CSS it's probably what I'm already doing. The issues with it are the following:

- The area behind the element isn't really blurred, just an arbitrary background image.
- The edges or the blurred area do not cleanly cut off the blur. This is a bit hard to describe, but just trust me when I say that it's doesn't look great.

Unless I missed something huge in all my searching, I think I'm going to need JS for this one.

Comment: If you want help with fixing your CSS solution, you need to post what you tried. Any other interpretation of this question makes it off-topic for SO.

Comment: I don't want help with my CSS solution–I want an entirely different solution. I'm trying to say that if someone intends to suggest a CSS only solution that I've likely already tried it and I am looking for alternatives. How can I change the wording of my question to better reflect this?

Comment: The problem isn't the wording, it's the question itself. SO is not for getting other people to design solutions or write code for you. You're expected to try this yourself, and if you can't get it working we'll help you fix it. But if you don't post any code, it's most likely not appropriate here.

Comment: That's unlucky since I haven't a clue how to accomplish what I want to do.

Comment: I'm not a CSS expert, but it seems like `z-index` should be a big part of the solution. Use an existing blur method for the background, then give the non-blurred part a higher z-index so it's displayed in front of the blurred part.

Answer (score 1):

Barmar is correct. Give two objects the same `absolute` position. Blur one object and assign it a lower `z-index`. Bob's your uncle.

If you need some clearer specifics, then please post your code following the SO guidelines.

Comment: "Bob's your uncle." XD